# Moving array elements left and right

Tags: java, arrays

So as part of the `Vector` class I'm trying to create, I also want the ability for the user to be able to shift the elements in the array an `'n'` number of places depending on what is specified. If the user inputs a number that is larger than the array size, then the elements continue shifting back to the start and moving. An example would be:

```
 1 2 3 4 (shifted 1) => 4 1 2 3

 1 2 3 4 (shifted 4) => 1 2 3 4

 1 2 3 4 (shifted 5) => 4 1 2 3
```

I don't have much code so far except:

```
public Vector shifted(int amount) {
  Vector vectorShifted = new Vector(length);

  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++);
    vectorShifted.elements[i] = this.elements[i + amount]
  }
  return vectorShifted;
}
```

However, when I run this program and a number greater than `length` is entered, an error is displayed. Is there a way of modifying this code in that any number, positive or negative can be inputted and shift the values across?

Comment: As you make a circular shift, add the modulo operator:


`vectorShifted.elements[i] = this.elements[(i + amount) % length]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like lazary2 said, you can use the modulo operator %

Change: 
`vectorShifted.elements[i] = this.elements[i + amount]`

to `vectorShifted.elements[i] = this.elements[(i + amount) % length]`

If you want to use Array:

`Integer[] array = {0,1,2,3,4};
Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(array), 3);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array)); //[2, 3, 4, 0, 1]`

Comment: When i run this program however it seems to be shifting it to the left instead of the right. How could i maybe fix that?

Comment: I assume that you haven't write your code. If you want you try to use Arrays.
Collections.rotate(Arrays.asList(array), 3);
If you need to use vector can you write the code that you are using?